# Boolean validation check cakephp not working

Tags: validation, cakephp, boolean

Hey trying to get a validation check working on a boolean field called 'activated'. Basically if the boolean is 1 then the account is active, meaning they can login. If it is anything else  then users cannot login.

Here is my check from the User Model:

```
public $checkActive = array(
        'activated'=>array(
                'rule'=>array('equalTo', '1'),
                'message'=>'The account must be activated, please check your email.'
            ));
```

Unfortunately users are able to login when they are not suppose to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that validation in models are only tested when data is being saved.

If you are using the Authentication component, you can define a 'scope' which is a condition which must equal true for the user to be authenticated.

```
'scope' => array('User.activated' => 1)
```

More info and an example: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html)

If you have written your own authentication then you could add the condition to your current find statement.

```
$this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'activated' =>1);
```

Hope this answers your question.